# ¿ Cambiar a version C# 7 en Visual Studio Community 2017?

Tags: visual-studio

¿ Como puedo cambiar a la versión 7 de C# para compilar los proyectos con Visual Studio Community 2017 ?

Lo he buscado en el menú Proyecto - Propiedades pero no me aparece ninguna opción de cambio de versión

Adjunto imagenes boton derecho en "Solucion" - "Propiedades":[image: Propiedades comunes]

[image: Propiedades de configuración]

Imágenes botón derecho en "Proyecto" - "Paginas de propiedades":
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Es sencillo. Debes ir a las propiedades del proyecto (pulsando con boton derecho en el proyecto, y seleccionando propiedades en el explorador de soluciones, o en Proyecto/Propiedades), y de ahí la pestaña Compilación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posteriormente, pulsa en Avanzadas, señalado en la captura anterior, y te aparecerá la siguiente pantalla donde puedes seleccionar la versión de C# a utilizar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque por lo general la opción por defecto es la última version de C#, con lo que ya  deberías estar usando la 7.

Comment: Si voy a menú "Ver" - "Pagina de propiedades" no me sale la ventana que has puesto de captura. ¿ Como voy a "Propiedades del Proyecto" ? Estoy usando Visual Studio Community 2017 con C# y WebForms / ASP. NET

Comment: @Popularfan ya veo..tal vez esas opciones son diferentes en el comunity pero hasta que llegue a casa no puedo verlo. Puedes de todas maneras revisar que tienes en la pestaña de opciones para MSBuild?

Comment: @Popularfan olvida lo que he dicho. El problema es porque tu proyecto es de tipo sitio web asp.net. Déjame investigar a ver como se hace en esos casos

Comment: @Popularfan en ese tipo de proyectos parece que no es tan sencillo. Prueba [esta solucion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42764174/579895)

Comment: Creia que era mas sencillo. Me lo miro a ver

Answer (score 0):

@Pikoh♦

Os adjunto captura me paso exactamente como a ti no encontraba el menú de acceso al compilador hasta que me di cuenta que no es la solución sino el archivo de proyecto[image: Acceder al menu version compilador]

Answer (score 0):

Me acaba de pasar lo mismo e instalé el paquete nuget `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotnetCompilerPlatform` para solucionarlo.